# library manage account with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have trouble creating a project with asp .net. and terelik
I have to create a system. Account management Everytime i want to know Which libraries help to create account management with .net and support the terelik ui
some thing like manage rule for the any method, just install packages then the packages has initial the table model controller or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are no package which you can just install and get everything already done but there are number of projects in code project site. You can download them and integrate. Beside that you can use Microsoft Identity which provide bootstrap code for user registration/login and you can customize according to your need and role base access can be simply done in mvc just by providing role in controller attribute.

And I am not aware of Telerik providing such functionality. You should implement those using Telerik controls.